# How to use indexes to access multiple elements in a list

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am currently making TicTacToe for a project using the turtle module. I made a list with the coordinates on where the turtle should go based on the input given by the user. After that, I made an if statement on if certain spots have been selected by the user, then the user would win. While making the if statement, I was using indexes to try to see if the User's inputs matched the actual coordinates. While checking in the if statement to see if specific cords match. I keep getting errors like:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I was wondering if I wrote it incorrectly. I also know that I poorly explained it, if there are some questions, please ask. I am also very new to coding and python. I have also wrote where the error would occur.

Here is the following code:

```
#Code for creating turtle and image as well

import turtle as trtl
TTT = trtl

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.addshape('O2.gif')
wn.addshape('X3.gif')

TTT.pensize(5)
TTT.speed(0)


#VARIABLES
lines = 0
x = 50
y = -50 
Available_Cords = [(-100,100),(0,100),(100,100),(-100,0),(0,0),(100,0),(-100,-100),(0,-100),(100,-100)]
Taken_Cords = [(10,10)]
X_Used_Cords = [(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0)]
Y_Used_Cords = [(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0)]
Current_Turn = 2

#Code For creating background
while lines < 2:
TTT.penup()
TTT.goto(x,-150)
TTT.pendown()
TTT.goto(x,150)

TTT.penup()
TTT.goto(-150, y)
TTT.pendown()
TTT.goto(150, y)

x = x + -100 
y = y + 100
lines = lines + 1

TTT.penup()
while True:
#code for X turn
while (Current_Turn % 2 == 0): 
  User_Input = int(input("X, Please enter where you like to go"))
  Current_Cord = Available_Cords[User_Input - 1]
  
  
  #Checking if the spot chosen has been taken, if yes then the if code will run
  if Current_Cord in Taken_Cords:
     
     print("This Spot is not Available, Try another one")

  #If the spot is available, then the Else code will run which will place the image in the spot chosen
  else:
     TTT.shape('X3.gif')
     TTT.goto(Available_Cords[User_Input - 1])
     TTT.stamp()
     Taken_Cords.append(Available_Cords[User_Input - 1])

     #Code for Adding to list to detect if the player has won
     X_Used_Cords.insert(User_Input-1 ,Available_Cords[User_Input-1])
     print(X_Used_Cords)
     del X_Used_Cords[User_Input]
    
     
     
     Current_Turn = Current_Turn + 1

#LOTS OF IF STATEMENTS TO CHECK IF X WON
if X_Used_Cords[0:3] == Available_Cords[0:3]:
  print("Congratulations, you won :)")
  wn.mainloop()

if X_Used_Cords[3:6] == Available_Cords[3:6]:
  print("Congratulations, you won :)")
  wn.mainloop()   

if X_Used_Cords[6:9] == Available_Cords[6:9]:
  print("Congratulations, you won :)")
  wn.mainloop()


#CODE WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

if X_Used_Cords[0,3,6] == Available_Cords[0,3,6]:
  print("Congratulations, you won :)")
  wn.mainloop()


#Code For Y Turn
while (Current_Turn % 2 != 0): 
  User_Input = int(input("Y, Please enter where you like to go"))
  Current_Cord = Available_Cords[User_Input - 1]
  
  
  if Current_Cord in Taken_Cords:
     print("This Spot is not Available, Try another one")
  
  else:
     TTT.shape('O2.gif')
     TTT.goto(Available_Cords[User_Input - 1])
     TTT.stamp()
     Taken_Cords.append(Available_Cords[User_Input - 1])
     Current_Turn = Current_Turn + 1

      #Code for Adding to list to detect if the player has won
     Y_Used_Cords.insert(User_Input-1 ,Available_Cords[User_Input-1])
     print(Y_Used_Cords)
     del X_Used_Cords[User_Input]

wn = trtl.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you post the full error message? Do you want us to *guess* where the error is being thrown? Please see [ask] and the [help]. Please always provide a [mcve]. The vast majority of this code is completely irrelevant. You could reproduce this problem with something like `data = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']; print(data[0, 2])` or something like that

Comment: Anyway, the error message is pretty clear: "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple". You seem to expec that `mylist[i, j, k]` will work. It doesn't. I suspect you just want something like `(mylist[i], mylist[j], mylist[k])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I just tried the method you suggested. Sadly when i used it, it would check if only one of those matched, not all three. Is there any for it to check all three?

Comment: Needs complete error message/traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on line 83: `X_Used_Cords[0,3,6] == Available_Cords[0,3,6]` (there might be other errors).

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

This syntax is invalid as you cannot slice a list with a tuple (`0,3,6`).

Instead either get the coordinates separately:

```
(X_Used_Cords[0] == Available_Cords[0]) and (X_Used_Cords[3] == Available_Cords[3]) and (X_Used_Cords[6] == Available_Cords[6])
```

or using `all`:

```
all(X_Used_Cords[i] == Available_Cords[i] for i in (0,3,6))
```

or use advanced slicing:

```
X_Used_Cords[0:7:3] == Available_Cords[0:7:3]
```

although this case works only as the indices are evenly spaced.